# Questions about amp-toolbox-optimizer

Tags: amp-html

I have my AMP site which we are interested in applying [AMP Server-side rendering](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/server-side-rendering/).

Using the tool [runkit](https://npm.runkit.com/amp-toolbox-optimizer?t=1565714465726) we convert with the conversion examples some links from our sites to measure the improvements of the transformed amp. I share two links that visualize these transformations.

- https://www.elimparcial.com/.tests/amp-toolbox-optimizer/test-nota-optimizer.html
- https://www.elimparcial.com/.tests/amp-toolbox-optimizer/test-nota-optimizer-two.html

Queries:

1- In both cases when optimizing the HTML the images are not visualized, can they help us identify the cause?

2- Anyway, the result of the optimized amp is not 50% as discussed in the documentation, comparing any of the two links with its [original amp](https://www.elimparcial.com/amp/sonora/sonora/Sonora-tiene-deficit-de-3-mil-434-efectivos-estatales-y-municipales-AMLO-20190813-0047.html), we do not identify performance improvements on web.dev or fast html load, how do we measure these improvements?

Do you know any live case to see the impact of the improvement by having optimized amp?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post the original version of your page. Otherwise it's not possible to reproduce your results.

Regarding your questions:

1. Images are not shown because of an incomplete transformation (the `<i-amphtml-sizer>` element is missing `style="display:block;padding-top:XXXX;"`. If you provide the original file, I can try to reproduce what's causing this.
2. The 50% improvement in FCP results from the AMP Boilerplate being removed. If you look at the source code of the transformed files, you'll notice that the boilerplate is still present. There are different reasons why the boilerplate cannot be removed. The best way to find out is to pass the `{ verbose: true }` option to AMP Optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the prompt response.

The original version of the test page is as follows https://www.elimparcial.com/amp/sonora/sonora/Sonora-tiene-deficit-de-3-mil-434-efectivos-estatales-y-municipales-AMLO-20190813-0047.html

I will do the tests with the active code of verbose.

We have also found that the transformation has some problem with our design icons that are used from the sources.